# How do I ask for user input until the input is valid?

Tags: java, exception, conditional-statements

I want to have the user input two doubles which represent the sides of a triangle, and then calculate the hypotenuse. First, the user specifies what command (A, B, C, or Q) they want, then for A and B (side input) they are asked to enter a double. Right now, when they don't enter a double, the program asks them for the first input (A, B, C,  Q). I want the program to just ask them for another double until the input is valid.

My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Double sideA = null;
    Double sideB = null;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Enter command: ");
        String command = scanner.nextLine();

        try {   // checks command, throws exception if not A, B, C or Q
            if (command.equals("A")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a value for side A:");
                sideA = scanner.nextDouble();                       // throws InputMismatchException if not a double
                scanner.nextLine();
                try {
                    if (sideA < 0 || sideA == 0.0) {
                        throw new InputMismatchException();
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("Value is invalid. Must be positve and a double.");
                }

            }
            else if (command.equals("B")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a value for side B:");
                sideB = scanner.nextDouble();                       // throws InputMismatchException if not a double
                scanner.nextLine();

                try {
                    if (sideB < 0 || sideB == 0.0) {
                        throw new InputMismatchException();
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("Value is invalid. Must be positive and a double.");
                }

            }
            else if (command.equals("C")) {
                Triangle calculate = new Triangle(sideA, sideB);
                System.out.println(calculate.calcHypotenuse());
                break;
            }
            else if (command.equals("Q")) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

        } 
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Command is invalid, Enter A, B, C, or Q.");
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Value is invalid. Must be positve and a double.");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: To help us answer your question, could you be more specific? Presently, the answer you're looking for based upon the question is a rewrite of your code with the bug fixed. This question does not follow [StackOverflow standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: see my edits. I think they clarify what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

Having a quick look at your code, you can acheive what you want simply by moving the command string outside the while loop

```
String command = null;
while (true) {

    if (command == null) {
        System.out.println("Enter command: ");
        command = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    ....

}
```

Also consider consolidating the `try-catch` code so that you are not duplicating code

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested while loop to get the desired double value:

```
private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

private double getDoubleInput() {
    double ret = -1;
    while (ret < 0) {
        try {
            ret = scanner.nextDouble(); 
        }catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.print("Enter a valid double value: ");
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This handles both NaNs and negative numbers by prompting the user for a valid double value until a positive double is inputted. Make sure to make the Scanner a class variable so this method can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first and for-most, please indent properly with enough comments to explain your thought process.

Secondly, there are still few things that are not clear.

```
try {   // checks command, throws exception if not A, B, C or Q
            if (command.equals("A")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a value for side A:");
                sideA = scanner.nextDouble();                       // throws InputMismatchException if not a double
                scanner.nextLine();
```

in the above mentioned code, in the last line, you have a input taken from Scanner class object, which is not stored into anything.

Why do you need it? What is its purpose?

Thirdly, there are a lot of code duplications, with the amount of `IF-ELSE-IF` in your code. Try this same code with **SWITCH**, this is precisely the problem that you can avoid if u use **SWITCH** instead of **IF-ELSE**.

And the reason for you still getting the **Prompt** to `enter a command` is because you have put it inside your while loop. Removing it from that place and replacing it outside will do the trick.

Which brings me to my final point, Once you have what you need *i.e.* *correct answer* or *exception for the invalid input*, then why do you need to keep checking the same statement again and again?

```
while(true){
      ......
      ......
      ......
}
```

will run infinitely, and keep on checking the same condition over and over again, giving you the same exception as your output **infinite** times.

To resolve this either remove the `while loop` or take another input from the user until he enters a desired value and then `break` once the **desired output** is reached.